# Peer connections stays in chrome://webrtc-internals/ even after it is disconnected

Tags: javascript, webrtc, chromium, rtcpeerconnection

We have developed a SFU conferencing solution. When a user  leaves the conference the peer connection does'nt end. it is showing in chrome://webrtc-internals/  with status closed.

1. Will this be counted as an active peer connection ?
2. Will this behaviour make the peer connection limit exceed, even though active peer connections count are within the limit.?

Answer (score 1):

According to the discussion about this [Chrome Bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=825576), Chrome has a hard limit of 500 peer connections and closed connections are also included until they are garbage collected by the browser. It seems like Firefox does not have the same problem.

To answer your question (seems to be a chromium problem):

1. It will be evaluated as if it is an active connection
2. It will count to the limit (at least on chromium-based browser)